# HTML/Javascript - Form Submit two values to one variable with one click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I am trying to create a submit "reset" button that set a variable to "true" and then back to "false" with one click. It sounds really simple and I have spent hours trying to figure this out but failed. Please help...

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="f1" action="">
    <button action="javascript:setReset(f1);">RESET</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="var1" name="var1" value="">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function setReset(formName) {
    document.getElementById("var1").value="true";
    document.getElementById(formName).submit();
    document.getElementById("var1").value="false";
    document.getElementById(formName).submit();
}
```

Comment: The form is supposed to interact with your server, not with JS. If you don't want to submit a form, use a regular button instead of the submit button (type of button) and attach a click listener to that button. If you want to submit the form, but don't want server's response to take a place, use AJAX to send the information to the server (type of button + click listener again).

Comment: You can't submit a form twice consecutively. Could you please try to explain, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am sending this to a controller. This will activate the reset function in my controller, which will turn off several other variables when the reset function is ON. However, the reset function needs to be turned off to re-enable the other variables. Is there no work around for this? I am not really familiar with AJAX but will learn it if needed.

Comment: You simply cannot do that. You need to use Ajax if you want to get that behavior.

Comment: You can call a controller function using an ajax function.  Depending on the circumstances, you may need to reload the page though.  [Here is an SO question/answer with working examples and detailed info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523270/call-controller-method-which-return-view-with-ajax-call-from-asp-net-view-page)

Comment: I am not sure what server-side language your controller is, so [here is a link for how to do it with PHP controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406690/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-controller)